# What angles are possible when combining two pipe fittings?

Tags: geometry, angle, visualization

Plumbers often combine two 45° elbows (1/8 bends) or a 45° wye and an 1/8 bend to give them more freedom through rotation before gluing PVC pipes.

### [image]

Often, this is necessary because the incoming pipe has a vertical angle (of 1/4" per foot) when viewed in elevation, the outgoing pipe has its own vertical angle (again of 1/4" per foot), and the plumber wants some horizontal angle between the two pipes (when viewed from above in plan).

[image]

For a single fitting, a previously answered question shows that the space of available angles forms a cone through rotation ([New angle formed after rotating pipe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544734/new-angle-formed-after-rotating-pipe)).

What is the space of available vertical and horizontal angles between the two pipes? How could I visualize this? Can this be generalized to other combinations of angle fittings (1/4 bends, 1/8 bends, and 1/16 bends)?

[image]

Comment: Nicely written and illustrated question.

Comment: This kind of question is not far from robotics issues.